# How to resume a suspended (tty input) process [unix/mac]?

Tags: macos, unix, terminal, tty

I've a background process running in Mac terminal

```
./scripts/start_emulator &
[1] 37194
```

After executing several steps, it automatically gets suspended with following message

```
Accept? (y/N):
[1]  + 37194 suspended (tty input)  ./scripts/start_emulator
```

How do I resume / continue this suspended process?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To add to the Chaitanya Bapats answer,

you can use `jobs` command to list the suspended jobs. The output will be something like this if you have more than one suspended jobs.

```
[1]  - suspended  sleep 400
[2]  + suspended  sleep 300
```

You can bring the job to foreground by using `fg`. If you have more than one suspended jobs, then you can use `fg %ID`. ID is the value inside `[]` in the output of `jobs` command.

Also, if you want to resume the job without bringing it to the foreground, you can use `kill -CONT` command. Example usage:

```
kill -CONT JOBID
```

You can also use `bg` command to move job to background. `bg` will resume the last suspended job. Also, `bg %ID` will resume the job with `[ID]` in jobs command output

Answer (score 2):

A process running in background [as commanded with `&` at the end] gets suspended while it is waiting for the input.

Indicator:

```
suspended (tty input)
```

In order to resume that suspended process, enter

```
fg
```

This brings the background process to the foreground
& then enter the input, in my case

```
y
```

The normal process execution should resume in foreground.